# Marker not moving continuously in react native maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm building an app using `react-native` and `react-native-maps` that shows a marker at user's current position and then as the user moves the marker also moves along with the user drawing a path behind.

Everything is working fine but when user's position changes it seems that marker movement is not continuous but moves a larger distance.

As you can see in the below images the movement of the marker is not continuous. Is there any solution for this?

I'm following this [tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTf2m.gif)

**Current scenario:**

[image]

**Required scenario:** 
[image]

```js
class AnimatedMarkers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: LATITUDE,
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      routeCoordinates: [],
      distanceTravelled: 0,
      prevLatLng: {},
      coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE
      })
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {},
      error => alert(error.message),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      }
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        const { coordinate, routeCoordinates, distanceTravelled } = this.state;
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

        const newCoordinate = {
          latitude,
          longitude
        };

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
          if (this.marker) {
            this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
              newCoordinate,
              500
            );
          }
        } else {
          coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();
        }

        this.setState({
          latitude,
          longitude,
          routeCoordinates: routeCoordinates.concat([newCoordinate]),
          distanceTravelled:
            distanceTravelled + this.calcDistance(newCoordinate),
          prevLatLng: newCoordinate
        });
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
  }

  calcDistance = newLatLng => {
    const { prevLatLng } = this.state;
    return haversine(prevLatLng, newLatLng) || 0;
  };

  getMapRegion = () => ({
    latitude: this.state.latitude,
    longitude: this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          showUserLocation
          followUserLocation
          loadingEnabled
          region={this.getMapRegion()}
        >
          <Polyline coordinates={this.state.routeCoordinates} strokeWidth={5} />
          <Marker.Animated 
            ref={marker => {
              this.marker = marker;
            }}
            coordinate={this.state.coordinate} />
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.bubble, styles.button]}>
            <Text style={styles.bottomBarContent}>
              {parseFloat(this.state.distanceTravelled).toFixed(2)} km
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't continuously get the position since the position is updated periodically depending on the device. You can save the last positions with a timestamp and interpolate the movement.

Comment: Use splines instead of polylines.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ohh I see do you have reference link that I can get help from?

Comment: What help? What do you want to do? Interpolation?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, interpolating the last position with the current one?

Comment: No, I don't know of sources for this. But you can read code of open source navigation apps.

Answer (score 1):

By default, we get location update every 100m.

To continuously get the location update we need to change the `distanceFilter` options available in the geolocation API.

```js
{ 
  enableHighAccuracy: true, 
  timeout: 15000, 
  maximumAge: 10000,  
  distanceFilter: 0, // add/update to get frequent location updates
}
```

PS: Instead of using the inbuilt deprecated `Geolocation` in React Native, better use [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) module.